# why list.Sort((x ,y) => x - y) has no memory allocation in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, garbage-collection

the C# source code:
[text](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646)

```
public void Sort(Comparison<T> comparison) {
    if( comparison == null) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match);
    }
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    if( _size > 0) {
        IComparer<T> comparer = new Array.FunctorComparer<T>(comparison);
        Array.Sort(_items, 0, _size, comparer);
    }
}
```

this line
IComparer<T> comparer = new Array.FunctorComparer<T>(comparison);
shows that every time you sort an array, it will create  a new object. But when I ran it many times, I found it has no allocation at all.Why?

Here is my test code.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    list.Add(1);
    list.Add(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        long cnt = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
        list.Sort((x ,y) => x - y);
        Console.WriteLine(GC.GetTotalMemory(false) - cnt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using .NET Framework or .NET? The source code you showed is for .NET Framework. [It is implemented differently in .NET](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs,a406b86aecf46aa1).

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain i am guessing he's thinking each item compared will be copied in memory. I don't think he knows that at worst it will simply use 1 extra pointer to allow shifting. Pls he's using `GC.GetTotalMemory` which isn't precise at all so he wont be seeing 4 bytes difference for sure :)

Comment: If you need to measure how much memory is being used, then you shouldn't be using any GC stuff. Instead, use a library like BenchmarkDotNet

Comment: @DavidG - though `BenchmarkDotNet` does use GC stuff, or doesn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure. I use rider to see the IL code, it also has code below:      IL_0031: newobj       instance void class [mscorlib]System.Comparison`1<int32>::.ctor(object, native int), I first found this problem in unity profiler,So I don't know that whether the comparison will be wrapped in an Array.FunctorComparer every time, which will cause heap allocation.

Comment: @Sweeper My code is .Net Framework, I viewed the two versions, they throw different exceptions. .Net Framework throws Exception.Match, which is the same with my code.

Comment: It is worth noting that List.Sort and Array.Sort are *in place*, so any memory overhead should be small and fixed. So it is likely not something to be concerned about.

Comment: @JonasH That's good practice~I'm just a little confused，3Q

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear if you are using .NET 6/7 or .NET Framework 4.x. However, the [`List<T>.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-7.0) method does allocate memory if you are using .NET Framework 4.x.

Instead of directly using the `GC` methods, it's far better to use a benchmarking library that is specifically designed to do things like this. I recommend [BenchmarkDotNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BenchmarkDotNet). For example, a small program like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Jobs;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<Benchmarks>();
    }
}

[MemoryDiagnoser] // output memory allocations
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net70)]
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net481)]
public class Benchmarks
{
    private readonly List<int> _list = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };

    [Benchmark]
    public void SortList()
    {
        _list.Sort((x, y) => x - y);
    }
}
```

Will give you output something like this:

| Method | Job | Runtime | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SortList | .NET 7.0 | .NET 7.0 | 7.989 ns | 0.1608 ns | 0.1343 ns | - | - |
| SortList | .NET Framework 4.8.1 | .NET Framework 4.8.1 | 28.208 ns | 0.5812 ns | 0.9385 ns | 0.0038 | 24 B |

Now you can see that it does indeed allocate either 0 bytes or 24 bytes depending on which framework you are using.

Comment: var list = new list<int> {1, 2} allocates memory, may not be sort's cost.But I'll try, 3Q

Comment: Ah sorry, I wrote that test far too quickly! Have fixed it now